# C# Reflection at run-time

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to get information about the fields, functions and threads of a some project, through another project.

As an example project that I want to explore, I created a field int x that initialize to 1.
The Main calls to function that changes the value of x to 2.
I stuck the Main in an endless loop.
I ran this project.

The second project:
Get the path to the EXE file of the first project, and load the assembly.
By reflection, i got the names of departments, functions and fields.
I tried to print the value of the field x by the function getValue. Instead of printing 2, 1 was printed.
i.e., the reflection refers to the values of the compiled-time, instead of the run-time.

what should i do?

Comment: do you mean you need to interrogate a different assembly dynamically?

Comment: This is not what reflection means in .NET world. I would recommend calling it something different.

Comment: Loading the assembly doesn't run the code. You haven't executed your `Main` and thus never updated `x`. You're trying to access in-memory values from a completely different process, and that's a whole different kettle of fish. =)

Comment: Where else would you do reflection, at compile-time?

Comment: I miss read this, you could setup a service endpoint to get the runtime value from another running project.  or just use sockets directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the new value, that's in memory, in the other process.

With Reflection you can however load that assembly, create an instance of that class and call Main explicitly and then check for the value of the int because then the code would be run by your process.

**Do not** expect to be able to sniff the values out of the memory space of another application with Reflection, that is not what Reflection does.

Comment: I added a thread that invoked the Main class, but it still does'nt work..   :(

Comment: @OrKedmi Why a separate thread? Try to load the assembly, create an instance, call the Main method and after it's finished, get the value of the field and see. It should show the new value of 2.

Comment: While the first project  is ran, I want to check each interval of time the value of X..
There's no point waiting until he will finish.